# how to perform SSL handshake in c# and access the url in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

am working on windows application where I need code for performing SSL handshake from client to server li have used x509 certificate for verification of SSL certificate and it validate the certificate successfully, but when I open the same url in browser( chrome, internet explorer,mozilla) I get an error saying err certificate is invalid.

Can someone help me achieve this.

Thanks

C

Comment: Certificate can be invalid for many reasons like dat expired.  You also may have in c# option to ignore certificate errors turned.  SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and must use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 do not support older encryption modes.  So there are lots of reasons for the certificate being invalid.

Comment: What I did is I installed the remote certificate in Client machine, still I can't find the solution.

Comment: Certificate has to be in both server and client.  TLS the client request version of TLS than server sends a certificate block with list of acceptable certificate names.  Then client looks up certificate in stores to find matching name.  Then client encrypts a message with certificate and  server sees if it can decrypt message with one of the certificates.  The certificate never gets sent between client and server.  The certificate has to be stored in two places on client.  The machine and the user stores.

Comment: "when I open the same url in browser( chrome, internet explorer,mozilla) I get an error saying err certificate is invalid", so what exactly is the error reported by the browser? To achieve maximum security, web browsers are currently quite strict on certificate verification, so they can report more issues than merely custom validation you perform in C# code (not to mention many applications skip validation and compromise on security).

Comment: Okk can you let me know is there a way i can log erros if there is certificate issue in c#